# add multiple leading zeros in odometer

Tags: php, mysql, odometer

I was tried reward polling using odometer, now I want my number polling is lead by zero,
**1,239,387** be **001,239,387**, 
it start from 123456789. When odometer is running, result without 00, just  **1,239,387**.
this code I tried with concat or add prefix to add lead zero. But if lead with > 0 it display

```
<?php 
$query="SELECT 
        CONCAT('00',MBR_ID) AS MBR_ID,
        NAME,
        RWD_DESC
FROM RTL.RWD_POLL RWD 
JOIN RTL.RWD_HEAD HED ON RWD.RWD_HEAD_NBR = HED.RWD_HEAD_NBR
WHERE HED.ACT_F = 1 AND RWD.DEL_NBR = 0
ORDER BY RWD_POLL_NBR DESC";
$result         = mysql_query($query);
$row            = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$MbrN           = $row['MBR_ID'];
$names          = $row['NAME'];
$reward         = $row['RWD_DESC'];
//$NoUndian = sprintf('%02d',$MbrN);
?>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){
 $('.odometer').html(<?php echo $NoUndian; ?> );
 }, 1000);
</script>
```

The result still 1,239,387 without zero.

Comment: `$('.odometer').html(<?php echo $NoUndian; ?> );` need to be `$('.odometer').html(<?php echo $MbrN; ?> );`

Comment: yeah, two of it can't work. i was tried with concat and add prefix. two of it what i tried.

Comment: try using str_pad instead: `$value = 1239387; echo str_pad($value, 9, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);` (https://repl.it/repls/NavyFrenchEquine)

Comment: %02d means “two numbers, prepend with zeroes if *less*.” You have already 7 numbers

Comment: The result still 1,239,387. @Brian.. so the problem is in odometer ?

Comment: If you are including commas, then you should use 11 instead of 9 as the padding length.

Comment: Also, yes you are correct. you will want to add quotes to the jquery statement.  `$('.odometer').html(<?php echo $NoUndian; ?> );` should actually be:  `$('.odometer').html(" <?php echo $NoUndian; ?> ");`

Comment: still not working @Brian.. after running it always change to 1,239,387 without zero, buat if i start lead with 1 or 2.. it work's like 111,239,387

Comment: You will have to quote the php statement. `<?php echo $NoUndian; ?>` needs to be `"<?php echo $NoUndian; ?>"`

Comment: still same @brian..

Comment: Can you take a look at the source for the generated html page and post what is there for the script tag?

Comment: what do u mean ? @brian

Comment: Go to the web page, do Ctrl+U, and show what is inside the `<script>` tag in the question.

Comment: $('odometer').html( " 001239387"); @Brian

Comment: So is it like this? https://jsbin.com/sevotarabu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: yes, like that @Brian

Comment: Is your output the same as the one that is shown in the jsbin?

Comment: output in web page in tag script is $('.odometer').html("001239387");, but output in UI is still 1239387 @Brian

Comment: instead of `.html()`, try `.text()`

Comment: still same 1239387 @Brian..

Comment: Can you try to create a blank php page containing nothing but this php query that echoes the $NoUndian variable?

Comment: yeah, if not use odometer, the result is correct be 001239387, i have tell u before if lead with another number it's work, but not with zero

Comment: very strange. Instead of jquery, try: `document.querySelector('.odometer').innerHTML = "<?php echo $NoUndian; ?>";`

Comment: this is the result 1,239,387

Comment: As a very minimal example, do something simple like: `<div class="odometer"></div>
<script>document.querySelector('.odometer').innerHTML = "<?php echo $NoUndian; ?>";</script>`

Comment: the result is 0

Comment: What is this result?

<div class="odometer">"<?php echo $NoUndian; ?>"</div>

Comment: the result 1,239,387 @Brian,

Comment: Okay, try this instead: 
`function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "00000000000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length-size);
}`
`$('.odometer').html(pad(<?php echo $NoUndian; ?>, 11));`